# Formbuilder Error DI

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to instantiate inject FormBuilder, however I keep getting:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error
```

This is what my Component looks like:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector:'user-new',
    templateUrl:'./user-new.template.html'
})

export class UserNewComponent{

    constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) _fb: FormBuilder){

    }

}
```

My Template has no Angular related code in it and is pure HTML.

Also, here is my app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostsComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    UserNewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoute,
    FormsModule 
  ],
  providers: [ UserService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: Is the `FormsModule` in the `imports` array for the current module? Also, why not just e.g. `private _fb: FormBuilder`.

Comment: Please re-read my comment! Give a [mcve] and any more information from the error message.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried adding `FormModule` to my app.module > imports, I still get the same error. I'm still a beginner in Angular2, I got this code from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Works fine for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/F5LHco?p=preview. Note that you need to use the `ReactiveFormsModule`, otherwise I'd expect to see `Error: No provider for FormBuilder!`. Also note that you still need to provide an access modifier if you want it to be made a property - see [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties).

Comment: You can check this link for concepts of forms you can find it under basic concepts https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, adding `ReactiveFormsModule` solved it

Comment: Please post an answer so that I can mark this question as solved :)

Comment: @RahulSingh Sure, will take a look at it